# Root and Ratio Tests (Rudin)

Tags: sequences-and-series

In Rudin's presentation of the Ratio test, he implicitly assumes that $\{a_{n}\}$  is a sequence of nonzero (complex) numbers, for otherwise the ratio $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ does not make sense for every $n$. This is made more clear in remark $3.26$ (on the scope of the ratio and root tests) where he cites theorem $3.27$ on sequences of *positive* numbers.

Now my question is this: We know that only the 'long term' behavior of a series really matters. So, can we fix the statement of the ratio test to allow for a finite number of zero terms?

Here's Rudin's statement: The series $\Sigma a_{n}$

(a) converges if $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_{n}|<1,$

(b) diverges if $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|\geq 1$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$ for some fixed $n_{0}$.

Now, part (b) is fine because we can simply take $n_{0}$ to be larger than the index of the last zero term. For part (a), the statement about $\limsup$ (and the corresponding statement about $\liminf$ in Apostol's text) seems to require that the ratio be defined. So do we 1) allow values in the extended real numbers, or 2) replace all terms that would be undefined with dummy values (say, 1?), or 3) start the sequence from a higher index (analogous to how we sometimes start with 0, sometimes 1)?

Comment: Why can't you look at the tail of the sequence (starting after the last 0 term) and just apply the original theorem from there?

Comment: So in a sense this is just changing the index to start at another value?